# how to remove substring from string c++

Tags: c++, split, token

I have a `string s="home/dir/folder/name"`

I want to split `s` in `s1="home/dir/folder"` and `s2="name";`

I did:

```
char *token = strtok( const_cast<char*>(s.c_str() ), "/" );
std::string name;
std::vector<int> values;
while ( token != NULL )
{
    name=token;

    token = strtok( NULL, "/" );
}
```

now `s1=name`. What about `s2`?

Comment: Please post proper code - this does not compile. For starters, you are missing a semicolon on std::string name.

Comment: **never** cast the result of `std::string::c_str()` to remove the const. This `const char *` is **not** modifiable in any reasonable way. Because of this, if you really need to use `strtok`, you must make a **copy**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several points: first, your use of `strtok` is undefined behavior; in
the case of g++, it could even lead to some very strange behavior.  You
cannot modify the contents of an `std::string` behind the strings back
and expect to get away with it.  (The necessity of a `const_cast` should
have tipped you off.)

Secondly, if you're going to be manipulating filenames, I'd strongly
recommend `boost::filesystem`.  It knows all about things like path
separators and the like, and the fact that the last component of a path
is generally special (since it may be a filename, and not a directory).

Thirdly, if this is just a one-of, or for some other reason you can't or
don't want to use Boost:

```
std::string::const_iterator pivot
    = std::find( s.rbegin(), s.rend(), '/' ).base();
```

will give you an iterator to the first character after the last '/', or
to the first character in the string if there isn't one.  After that,
it's a simple to use the two iterator constructors of string to get the
two components:

```
std::string basename( pivot, s.end() );
std::string dirname( s.begin(), pivot == s.begin() ? pivot : pivot - 1 );
```

And if you later have to support Windows, just replace the `find` with:

```
static std::string const dirSeparators( "\\/" );
std::string::const_iterator pivot
    = std::find_first_of( s.rbegin(), s.rend(),
                          dirSeparators.begin(), dirSeparators.end() );
```

Comment: @sunset No, because there is no correct use of `strtok`.  The function is only present in C++ because it is present in C, and it's only present in C for reasons of backwards compatibility.  There is no way to use it with `std::string` without copying the string into a `char[]`.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend against using `strtok`. Take a look at [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) instead (here are some [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm)).

Alternatively, to simply find the position of the last `'/'`, you could use `std::string::rfind`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::string s = "home/dir/folder/name";
  std::string::size_type p = s.rfind('/');
  if (p == std::string::npos) {
    std::cerr << "s contains no forward slashes" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::string s1(s, 0, p);
    std::string s2(s, p + 1);
    std::cout << "s1=[" << s1 << "]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s2=[" << s2 << "]" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx a lot! in s1 ill have the name of the file and in s2 the path,no?

Comment: Boost tokenizer is probably overkill, but if he's doing a lot of this sort of thing, Boost filesystem has all sorts of helpful functions.

Comment: @sunset: The other way around (as per your spec: **I want to split s in s1="home/dir/folder" and s2="name"**).

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is only to get the position of the last `\` or `/` in your `string`, you might use [string::find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) which does exactly that.

From there, you can use [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) or the constructor for `std::string` that takes iterators to get the sub-part you want.

Just make sure the original string contains at least a `\` or `/`, or that you handle the case properly.

Here is a function that does what you need and returns a `pair` containing the two parts of the path. If the specified path does not contain any `\` or `/` characters, the whole path is returned as a second member of the pair and the first member is empty. If the path ends with a `/` or `\`, the second member is empty.

```
using std::pair;
using std::string;

pair<string, string> extract_filename(const std::string& path)
{
  const string::size_type p = path.find_last_of("/\\");

  // No separator: a string like "filename" is assumed.
  if (p == string::npos)
    return pair<string, string>("", path);

  // Ends with a separator: a string like "my/path/" is assumed.
  if (p == path.size())
    return pair<string, string(path.substr(0, p), "");

  // A string like "my/path/filename" is assumed.
  return pair<string, string>(path.substr(0, p), path.substr(p + 1));
}
```

Of course you might as well modify this function to throw an error instead of gracefully exiting when the path does not have the expected format.

Answer (score 1):

Check out **[boost string split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id2896235)**.

Example:

```
string str1("hello abc-*-ABC-*-aBc goodbye");
typedef vector< iterator_range<string::iterator> > find_vector_type;
find_vector_type FindVec; // #1: Search for separators
ifind_all( FindVec, str1, "abc" ); // FindVec == { [abc],[ABC],[aBc] }
typedef vector< string > split_vector_type;
split_vector_type SplitVec; // #2: Search for tokens
split( SplitVec, str1, is_any_of("-*"), token_compress_on ); 
// SplitVec == { "hello abc","ABC","aBc goodbye" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `strtok` on `std::string`.
`strtok` would modify the string. It break the `c_str()` contract.

Doing `const_cast<>` is a big sign for error.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the string methods:

```
std::string  s="home/dir/folder/name"
std::string::size_type n = s.find_last_of("/");
std::string  s1 = s.substr(0,n);

if (n != std::string::npos) // increment past the '/' if we found it
{  ++n;
}
std::string  s2 = s.substr(n);
```

Two bits of advice:

- Don't use strtok **EVER**
- If you are playing with file system paths look at [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)
- If you want to play generally with tokenization use the stream operators
- Or boost::tokenizer